# Is it safe to delete Flutter "build" folders from computer's drive manually?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code, build, diskspace

I have 63,96 GBs of Flutter build folders on my computer's drive.

Although none of them is a commercial project I do not want to lose hours of practice and hard work.

Is it safe to delete them manually or shoud I follow a different approach like "flutter clean" every single project before I quit Android studio or VS Code?

Thanks in advance.

With love,
Oz

Answer (score 6):

It's safe to delete the `build` folder from a Flutter project.

The [`flutter clean` command](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f98c4683170a14d1b9bfa563acad5f01eda304cd/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/clean.dart#L28) does just that (as well as deleting some other folders, like `.dart_tool`):

```
@override
final String description = 'Delete the build/ and .dart_tool/ directories.';
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter does incremental builds, placing files in the build folder. Deleting the folder may corrupt your builds or cause errors, which could then be fixed by

```
flutter clean
```

So, in general manually deleting the build folder wont cause you to lose data / code, but it may cause difficult to track down errors sometime. A better approach might be to run flutter clean when you are done to free up space.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.